# AWS can't deregister EC2 from ELB during deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm using codeDeploy to deploy new code to my EC2 instances.

Here my appspec file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: v1
    destination:  /somewhere/v1
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: script/deregister_from_elb.sh
      timeout: 400
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - v1/script/deregister_from_elb.sh
[stderr]Running AWS CLI with region: eu-west-1
[stderr]Started deregister_from_elb.sh at 2017-03-17 11:44:30
[stderr]Checking if instance i-youshouldnotknow is part of an AutoScaling group
[stderr]/iguessishouldhidethis/common_functions.sh: line 190: aws: command not found
[stderr]Instance is not part of an ASG, trying with ELB...
[stderr]Automatically finding all the ELBs that this instance is registered to...
[stderr]/iguessishouldhidethis/common_functions.sh: line 552: aws: command not found
[stderr][FATAL] Couldn't find any. Must have at least one load balancer to deregister from.
```

Any ideas why is this happening? I suspect that the message "aws: command not found" could be the issue, but I have awscli installed

```
~$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.63 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-95-generic botocore/1.5.26
```

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code snippets from the failing scripts, with secrets removed?

Comment: the scripts are publicly available here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/load-balancing/elb